# Grunt.js - Removing/Cleaning folder on remote server

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs

In my project, I have two servers: Development and Production. I am managing static files (CSS/JS, etc) with Git, and DB deployment with Grunt. But after deploying the database, I need to remove Cache folder from my Production server. How can I do it with Grunt?

And, by the way, can I manage my files without Git using only Grunt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought, this was really easy:

For this king of task, all you need is [**grunt-shell**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell) and [**grunt-ssh**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ssh) packages. I faced only one problem with this - SSH was refusing connections because of ssh-agent was not active at the moment. Here is the sample code for pulling the git commits to remote server and deploying the database:

```
shell: {
  git: {
    command: ['eval `ssh-agent -s`', 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/yourKey.pem', 'grunt sshexec:gitpull'].join(' && ')
  },
  db: {
    command: ['eval `ssh-agent -s`', 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/yourKey.pem', 'grunt db_push', 'grunt sshexec:clear'].join(' && ')
  }
},
sshexec: {
  gitpull: {
    command: ['cd /var/www/', 'sudo -u yourSudoUser git pull --no-edit'].join("&&"),
    options: {
      host: 'youHost.com',
      username: 'username',
      agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    }
  },
  clearCache: {
    command: ['cd /var/www/core', 'sudo rm -rf cache'].join("&&"),
    options: {
      host: 'yourHost.com',
      username: 'username',
      agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    }
  }
}
```

**--no-edit** - if not set, git providing a window from GNU nano, where you must edit your commit message. This window cannot be closed, because Nano shortcuts will not work in current session.

**'eval `ssh-agent -s`', 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/yourKey.pem'** - starts **SSH-agent** and adding you keyPair. **NB!** Notice, that *grunt sshexec:gitpull* executing within the shell task, after ssh-agent starts. Otherwise you will not reach ssh-agent when executing sshexec in a separate task.

**'grunt db_push'** - task for **grunt-deployments** module.

**One more thing:** Consider updating Grunt and npm to the latest versions with `npm update npm -g` and `npm install grunt@0.4.4 -g`. After update this tasks went really smooth.